# Type annotations: Extract inner type from container type

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, type-annotation

I have the following setup:

```py
from typing import List
a = List[int]
foo(a) == int
```

What `foo` can I use to get `int` out of `List`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute `__args__` in order to take out the `int`.

```py
from typing import List
a = List[int]
print(a.__args__[0])
```

Result: `<class 'int'>`

Comment: `typing.get_args` would be a safer way to do this, given that the `__args__` attribute is an undocumented implementation detail. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args